# React router and nested layouts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have the following routes

```
import React from 'react'
import { IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router'
import RootComponent from './containers/RootComponent'
import BaseLayout from './components/BaseLayout'
import AuthenticatedLayout from './components/AuthenticatedLayout'
import Auth from './containers/Auth'
import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard'
import Inbox from './containers/Inbox'
import Schedule from './containers/Schedule'

export default (
  <Route path='/' component={BaseLayout}>
    <Route path='auth' component={Auth} />
    <Route component={AuthenticatedLayout}>
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path='Inbox' component={Inbox} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
)
```

**Questions:**

When I visit "/", `AuthenticatedLayout` and `Dashboard` doesn't appear.

1. How can I fix this?
2. Is `react-router` supposed to be used like this?

**EDIT:**

I tried changing `<Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} />` to `<IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />`. Same result.

Answer (score 3):

If you want `Dashboard` to appear by default you should add `Dashboard` in as an `IndexRoute` instead of assigning it a path. If you would like `/dashboard` to also direct to `Dashboard` you can use a `Redirect`.

Comment: I changed dashboard route to: `<IndexRoute component={Dashboard} />`, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with the following routes:

```
import React from 'react'
import { IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router'
import RootComponent from './containers/RootComponent'
import BaseLayout from './components/BaseLayout'
import AuthenticatedLayout from './components/AuthenticatedLayout'
import Auth from './containers/Auth'
import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard'
import Inbox from './containers/Inbox'
import Schedule from './containers/Schedule'
import NotFound from './components/NotFound'

export default (
  <Route component={BaseLayout}>
    <Route path='auth' component={Auth} />
    <Route component={AuthenticatedLayout}>
      <Route path='/' component={Dashboard} />
      <Route path='inbox' component={Inbox} />
    </Route>
    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
  </Route>
)
```